# Change Size of UIScrollView dynamically in autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout

[image: Constraints For ScrollView]  [image: Constraints for ScrollView]  [image: Constraints for ScrollView] [image: Constraints for ScrollView]
I have a `UIScrollView` in my app. I need the `UIScrollView` to change its height dynamically. I have already tried `_scrollArea.contentSize=CGSizeMake(_contentView.frame.size.width, x* _contentView.frame.size.height);` (with various values for x), but the scroll view is unaffected. the size of the `UIScrollView` is

> 320,568

And the size of the `_contentView` is

> 320,1100

So the `UIScrollView` needs a minimum height of 568 and a maximum height of 1100 (depending on certain app logic). I have embedded the whole thing into `AutoLayout`

NOTE:ContentView is INSIDE the `UIScrollView`

Comment: have you given a height constraint to the UIScrollView?

Comment: can you please show the part of the code where you set autolayout.

Comment: no. only trailing and leading spaces to the containerview and equal widths to the container view

Comment: i set the auto layout in the storyboard

Comment: Where did you set the contentSize? Try it from `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Comment: i set the contentSize from the storyboard. Pinned the height to 1100

Comment: Try setting the content size from `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method. Also I see some duplicate constraints there.

Comment: One way to increase the size of `UIScrollView` is to connect the constraint outlet as Pritesh below has pointed out,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86871/discussion-between-sreejith-and-sidharth-j-dev).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to do is take outlet of height constant and change it as per your requirement

see the below screen shots

[image]

now you should use below code

```
 self.scrollViewHeight.constant = 347; // set the height which you want to fix.
```

Comment: I dont have a height constraint now. What shoul I set the height to? 568?

Comment: This didnt work. I pinned the height, but it keeps scrollin